# Collect value from select option in from and insert database using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I tried many different way but it's not work.
Collect value from select option and insert database
Here is my code

************register.blade.php**********

```
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="education_medium" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Education Medium') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select class="form-control @error('education_medium') is-invalid @enderror" name="education_medium" required autocomplete="education_medium" autofocus>
                                <option value="1">Bangla Medium</option>
                                <option value="2">English Version</option>
                                <option value="3">English Medium</option>
                                <option value="4">Madrasa Medium</option>
                                <option value="5">Technical Medium</option>
                            </select>

                            @error('education_medium')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

****************RegisterController.php**************

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'education_medium' => ['required', 'string', 'max:100'],
    ]);
}


protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'education_medium' => $data['education_medium'],
    ]);
}
```

****************user-table.php**************

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to add a table to the database using the below query
**In user-table**
add the below code

```
$table->string('education_medium');
```

**In the Controller**

```
public function create()
 {
 $data = Request()->education_medium;
 $table = new User(); 
 $table->education_medium = $data;
 $table->save();
}
```

The User is the model that is in App\User and you also need to import that model